# Force Windows to Add Second Wifi Card

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10

I have two wifi cards installed on my laptop Intel 4965AGN and 3965ABG, usually it has no problem recognizing two wifi cards (I use two wifi networks) until I installed AirServer today. It basically deleted my 3965ABG and installed something called Microsoft A9 as an Ethernet connection. So I no longer can use both of my wifi networks. I uninstalled AirServer and uninstalled the Microsoft A9, but when I scan for new hardware it returned nothing. I did a restart and it does see the wifi card in my BIOS, but not in Windows. How can I force Windows 10 to reinstall the lost wifi card back?

P.S., I have no tried to unplug the wifi card and replug it back because it requires me to take apart my laptop.

Comment: Have you tried System Restore to go back to a previous restore point? Apparently it may have been disabled since the Windows 10 update, which would be annoying as it could well be your best bet, still worth a look though as I've used it on at least one of my machines lately. http://home.bt.com/tech-gadgets/computing/how-to-fix-windows-10-problems-with-system-restore-11364008291943

Comment: @Mokubai system restore was more time than taking apart the laptop so I did just that, now it works.